# Reply to comment using Facebook Graph API

Tags: reply

I am using Facebook Graph API in my project. If i want to create comment, I use this request to fb api:

> POST /{parent_comment_id}/comments?message={message}

process ok , But I try to reply my friend's comments

> POST /{comment_id_child}/comments?message={message}
>   It error
>
> {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
>       "type": "OAuthException",
>       "code": 10,
>       "fbtrace_id": "DGd2yf5YMvu"
>     }
>   }

[image: example]

I'm auto-reply reply comment profile but it's almost not running the comment of a friend. just run the original comment ID